# Trying to read FormsAuthentication tickets to read in other areas of site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

NOTE: I have included 3 links in here to my localhost areas but could not submit the post so I seperetaed them with a space character so it would post on stackoverflow.

I currently have 2 ASP.NET MVC apps in my solution. First I run the first one by setting it to be startup project. It goes to the login page, from there once the data has been entered I execute the following code:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, login.LoginDataContract.MSISDN, DateTime.Now,
                                                           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble("30")), true, "");

            string cookieContents = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieContents)
                             {
                                 Expires = authTicket.Expiration,
                                 //Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                                 //Path = "http://localhost"
                                 Domain = ""
                             };

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
```

As you can see I have set the Domain = "", so theoretically speaking it should work on any thing under my http: //localhost. Then I have set the persist security of the cookie to true so I can access it from any where under localhost.

The cookie writes fine and I get logged in and all godd for now. BTW the url for this login page is: http //localhost/MyAccount/Login

Now then I stop the solution and set the other MVC apps to be the startup. Then I run it. The URL for the second site is: http: //localhost/WebActivations/
Here is the code in the other apps start controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        // PASHA: Added code to read the authorization cookie set at
        // login in MyAccount *.sln

        for (int i = 0; i < System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Count;i++)
        {
            Response.Write(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i].Name + " " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i].Value);
        }

        HttpCookie authorizationCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName.ToString()];

        // decrypt.
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authorizationForm = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authorizationCookie.Value);

        ViewData["Message"] = authorizationForm.UserData[0].ToString();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is in this Home controller when I run the solution it cannot read the authentication cookie, you see the loop there it does not find the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

But once it crashes in Firefox I have a look in the Page Info and then security and Cookies and its there and its the same cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Domain="localhost"`

Comment: My bad in both the web.configs of both sites I forgot to add the   <mahineKey> element.

Comment: i worked on that damn problem for like 14 hours and that damn machine key solved it. i love u bro :)

Answer (score 0):

My bad in both the web.configs of both sites I forgot to add the mahineKey element.